# PostgreSQL выборка суммирование проверка подсчет

Tags: sql, postgresql

есть таблица вида:

```
xxx 10 time1 
xxx 11 time1
zzz 15 time3
xxx 14 time2
xxx 22 time2
zzz 16 time3
xxx 1  time4
xxx 2  time4
```

мне необходимо выбрать записи по ключу xxx совершенные в одно время (ключ time1, time2), за интервал времени, сложить и проверить соответствие условию >5,

после этого получить количество таких сумм (count) удовлетворяющих данному условию (>5), продвинулся в этом направлении но есть трудности...
В результате должно вывести: 2

```
select quantity, timestamp 
from   table1 t1 
where  exists (
         select 1 
         from   table1 t2 
         where  t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp 
         and    t1.id <> t2.id 
         and    t1.timestamp >=  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '108 hour' 
         and    t1.side = 'xxx')
```

Comment: Добавьте полученный результат и тот, который должен был бы получитьяс. И не понял про условие `>5`. Это вообще о чем?

Comment: И почему 2. Чего 2? ?

Answer (score 0):

Создадим табличку и заполним:

```
create table table1(side varchar(10), id integer, timestamp varchar(10));
insert into table1 values('xxx', 10, 'time1');
insert into table1 values('xxx', 11, 'time1');
insert into table1 values('zzz', 15, 'time3');
insert into table1 values('xxx', 14, 'time2');
insert into table1 values('xxx', 22, 'time2');
insert into table1 values('zzz', 16, 'time3');
insert into table1 values('xxx', 1,  'time4');
insert into table1 values('xxx', 2,  'time4');
```

Запрос:

```
select t1.side, t1.timestamp, count(1)
from   table1 t1 
inner  join table1 t2
on     t1.id != t2.id
and    t1.side = t2.side
and    t1.timestamp = t2.timestamp
where  t1.side ='xxx'
group  by t1.side, t1.timestamp
--having count(1) > 5
```

Результат:

```
side  |timestamp  |count
------------------------
xxx   |time1      |2
xxx   |time2      |2
xxx   |time4      |2
```